# What does (*p_z[id])(p_z[id]->size() - 1) do?

Tags: c++

I've never used c++ and I'm converting a C++ code to Python.  This line was hard to Google and I could not figure out whether my interpretation is correct.

We have p_z, which is declared as a `vector<shared_ptr<ArrayXd>>`.  `ArrayXd` appears to be something from the Eigen library and represents a 1d dynamic array.  Then:

```
(*p_z[id])(p_z[id]->size() - 1)
```

To me, it looks like p_z is a jagged 2d array.  Thus it seems that it's accessing the last column of row "id".  However, the notation is quite elaborate for simply accessing an array element compared to the more abstract languages I work with, so confirmation or further explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `ArrayXd`? More context would help.

Comment: It appears to be some kind of dynamic array with 1 dimension?

Comment: *"simply a 2d array"* - If only

Comment: Yes I removed the "simply" part after re-reading my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't understand complex code, you can simplify it, even without understanding. In this case, `p_z[id]` appears twice, so you can introduce a temporary variable for it:

```
vector< shared_ptr <ArrayXd> > p_z;
shared_ptr <ArrayXd> temp = p_z[id];
(*temp)(temp->size() - 1)
```

Now, you can see that `temp` gets dereferenced twice, using `operator*` and `operator->`. You can introduce a temporary variable for that too.

```
vector< shared_ptr <ArrayXd> > p_z;
shared_ptr <ArrayXd> temp1 = p_z[id];
ArrayXd& temp2 = *temp1;
(temp2)(temp2.size() - 1)
```

Remove extra parentheses:

```
ArrayXd& temp2 = ...;
temp2(temp2.size() - 1)
```

So your `ArrayXd` class has `operator()` and `size()` method, both of which are being called here. If you had brackets instead of parentheses, it would access the last element in array `temp2`, but you have parentheses here. Common sense tells me that `operator()` should do mostly the same as `operator[]` (possibly with small differences, like checking for out-of-range access), so yes, this code accesses the last element of the array.

Or, if we remove temporary variables:

`p_z` is an array of pointers to arrays (2-D array). Your code goes to index `id` in this array, and accesses the last element of the corresponding array. But you should verify your `operator()` - does it really do normal access, like `operator[]`?